# Error on Ajax call -> two files are sent instead of one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I need you to help me on a basic ajax call that i use for a login button.
There's a form to fulfil and then press "login" button, this will normally call a php file that will check and treat the login action.

The problem is that when i try to log, i have two files sent instead of one. I mean i expect this action to call the login.php file and to send back a reply with an object, but there's a first request that appears in red my developper console and another file that i didn't want to call that appears just under the first call.

[Here's what i see on my chrome developper console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBOvk.png)

The problem is certainly in my code, i must have written some bad code either in my JS file or php, so here they are :
- JS ajax call on click this function

```
logIn(pseudo, mdp, callback) {
    var var_request = {};
    var_request['pseudo'] = pseudo;
    var_request['mdp'] = mdp;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/webservices/logIn.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: var_request,
        timeout: kTimeout,
        success: function() {
            // callback();
            alert('good');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('function error');
        }
    });
},
```

and the php file requested is

```
include("connexion_bdd.php");

$pseudo = $_POST["pseudo"];
$mdp    = $_POST["password"];

$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM joueurs WHERE nickname = ?');
$req->execute(array($pseudo));

$reponse = $req->fetch();

if (!$reponse) {
    $return = array('error'=>'Pseudo non existant');
} else if ($reponse['mdp'] != $mdp) {
    $return = array('error'=>'Mauvais mot de passe');
} else {
    $return = array('error'=>'aucune erreur');
}

print(json_encode($return));
```

Thank you guys for reading and helping me! i guess i have done something bad but i can't see, i'm not very experienced, so don't be surprised if it seems easy for you to solve it ^^

see ya :)

Comment: Have you run `event.preventDefault()` to stop the form submitting as nomal when you are running this javascript code in its place

Comment: Can we see how you call the `logIn()` possibly an issue with form submission.

Comment: I'm gonna try this code @RiggsFolly, thx

Comment: Yes @VinnyMannello the login function is in the Webservices object that i created. 
the call of it is 
$('#loginSubmit').off('click');
$('#loginSubmit').on('click', function() {
 if ($('#pseudoC').val() == "") {
  alert('remplir le pseudo');
 } else if ($('#mdpC').val() == "") {
  alert('remplir le mdp');
 } else {    
                //Parameters
                var pseudo = $('#pseudoC').val();
  var mdp = $('#mdpC').val();

  Webservices.logIn(pseudo, mdp, function(reponse) {
                alert(reponse);
  });
 }
});

Comment: @AurelCA it looks like @RiggsFolly is on the right track... What does the `<form></form>` look like?

Answer (score 2):

Try this (switch `$("#your-form")` to your form ID):

```
$("#your-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent form submission and do your code instead...
    if ($('#pseudoC').val() == "") {
        alert('remplir le pseudo');
    } else if ($('#mdpC').val() == "") {
        alert('remplir le mdp');
    } else {
        //Parameters
        var pseudo = $('#pseudoC').val();
        var mdp = $('#mdpC').val();

        //Faire le check bdd si le pseudo existe et s'il est bien associé à ce mdp
        Webservices.logIn(pseudo, mdp, function(reponse) {
            alert(reponse);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply,

Thank y'all for the answers, it works now, i only have one lil problem : the data returned by my ajax call is not a JSON although i return a JSON in php with

print(json_encode($reponse));

Do i have to do anything else to treat the answer as a JSON?